# AWS Cloudformation - can't add multiple subnet associations to a public routing table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

We have a VPC with an Internet Gateway. We have 3 subnets (one in each AZ) and want to use one routing table for all three. This RT contains a rule to route 0.0.0.0/0 to the igw however when we try associate more than one subnet with this RT the stack creation fails on creating the routing rule, giving the following error message:

```
route table rtb-xxxxxxx and network gateway igw-xxxxx belong to different networks.
```

This is weird because the igw isn't attached to a subnet, it's attached to the VPC itself.

What I have to do to get the template working is to only have 1 subnet association with the RT and then update the stack afterwards with the other two.

I've tried adding 2 Wait Conditions, one tied to the creation of the RT and the other to the creation of the routing rule however they don't fix the problem - I still get the same error on the same damn rule :(

Can anyone shed some light on what I need to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6):

As @Marcus explained in his response to his own question; it is the lack of the [DependsOn](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute when you create an [AWS::EC2::Route](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-route.html) entry where you specify a [Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-internet-gateway.html).

> For route entries that specify a gateway, you must specify a dependency on the gateway attachment resource.

Having received the same error and scratching my head as to how this failed when the IGW is attached to the VPC it was a simple change in the `AWS::EC2::Route` declaration.

#### Failing CFN:

```
"VPC" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC",
    "Properties" : {"CidrBlock" : "10.1.0.0/16"}
},
"InternetGateway" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
},
"InternetGatewayAttachment" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
    "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "VPC"},
        "InternetGatewayId" : {"Ref" : "InternetGateway"}
    }
},
"ManagementRouteTable" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
    "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "VPC"}
    }
},
"NATDefaultRoute" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Route",
    "Properties" : {
        "RouteTableId" : {"Ref" : "ManagementRouteTable"},
        "DestinationCidrBlock" : "0.0.0.0/0",
        "GatewayId" : {"Ref" : "InternetGateway"}
    }
}
```

#### Working CFN:

```
"VPC" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC",
    "Properties" : {"CidrBlock" : "10.1.0.0/16"}
},
"InternetGateway" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
},
"InternetGatewayAttachment" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
    "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "VPC"},
        "InternetGatewayId" : {"Ref" : "InternetGateway"}
    }
},
"ManagementRouteTable" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
    "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "VPC"}
    }
},
"NATDefaultRoute" : {
    "DependsOn" : "InternetGatewayAttachment",
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Route",
    "Properties" : {
        "RouteTableId" : {"Ref" : "ManagementRouteTable"},
        "DestinationCidrBlock" : "0.0.0.0/0",
        "GatewayId" : {"Ref" : "InternetGateway"}
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the code example. this was exactly my problem!

Answer (score 5):

are you sure you've attached the InternetGatway to a VPC (or the same VPC as the route table). In cloud formation this looks something like...

```
    "AttachInternetGateway" : {
       "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
       "Properties" : {
          "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "YourVpc" },
          "InternetGatewayId" : { "Ref" : "InternetGateway" }
       }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix. I was on the right track with the Wait Conditions however it turns out I needed to add a [DependsOn](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute to the rule so that it depended on the igw being created first.

Comment: can you accept an answer? if this is the one, can you show the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

That's how we associate multiple subnets with the same Route Table:

```
...
"PublicSubnetA": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties": { "AvailabilityZone": "..",
                    "CidrBlock": "...",
                    "VpcId": { "Ref": "VPC" },
                    "Tags": [ .. ] }},
"PublicSubnetB": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties": { "AvailabilityZone": "..",
                    "CidrBlock": "...",
                    "VpcId": { "Ref": "VPC" },
                    "Tags": [ .. ] }},
"RouteTableIGW": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
    "Properties": { "VpcId": { "Ref": "VPC" },
                    "Tags": [ .. ]}},
"...": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
    "Properties": { "RouteTableId": { "Ref": "RouteTableIGW" },
                    "SubnetId":     { "Ref": "PublicSubnetA" }}
},
"...": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
    "Properties": { "RouteTableId": { "Ref": "RouteTableIGW" },
                     "SubnetId":    { "Ref": "PublicSubnetB" }}
},
...
```

And it works just fine. I associate this way one IGW-directed Route Table with 2 public subnets and another NAT-directed Route table with 4 private subnets.

Comment: It fails on the AWS::EC2::Route if there is more than one AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation pointing to the AWS::EC2::RouteTable

Comment: That's how I add a route: `{ "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route", "Properties": { "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", "RouteTableId": { "Ref": "RouteTableIGW" }, "GatewayId": { "Ref": "IGW" }}}`

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much how mine looks :( I'm thinking that I need to use a DependsOn somewhere, I'll have to look through the documentation again

Comment: I checked it - we don't have any dependencies for VPC pieces declared. May be it's something Region-related, we're in us-west-2.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the attachgateway for attaching multiple subnets with route table and internet gateways . Thus it attaches the internetgateway with the vpc